# Overriding camera to show screen

Tags: macos, camera

let's say I want to share my screen in a facetime call. If it's possible, how would I edit where the app looks to the camera input, but instead give it a video feed of the screen?, or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for something like [WebCamStudio](http://www.ws4gl.org/).

I have used it successfully even on a netbook to add information to things like Hangouts and other video/web conferences.